# How does a principal protected note pay the return on the market, on the whole principal?

Tags: options, put-call-parity

A real life principal protected note pays exactly the index return with 50% participation and a max 3y return of 30%:

total_principle*(end_price/start_price-1)*50%

These are all of the features, including fineprint.
How would you achieve this?
Could a call option plus a strip bond always achieve the exact same return as the index (for the total principal)?

Update
The rfr is 4%.

Comment: First of all it is 50% participation, not the whole principal, second they sell calls struck at 30% above market in order to help pay for the purchase of ATM calls.

Comment: Thank you this is the answer Im looking for. A zero coupon bond plus a bull spread would do it.

Comment: I will look into how to calculate the equilibriim participation rate (set to 50% here), likely requires calculating the leverage not sure if the volatility of the option is a factor.

Answer (score 1):

You haven’t really given enough details of the trade, but I believe the answer is that when rates are 0.5%, there is not enough left over to purchase many call options so the returns are more limited.  In other words, the payoff of the note is more interesting when rates are higher.